# mix-mode X509 Authentication with Spring 3.1

Tags: ssl, spring-security, tomcat7, x509

I am somewhat new to Spring and a novice in SSL authentication.

My question is that I have a web application which works fine with form-based authentication. I need part of my application to be automatically authenticated using SSL client authentication.

What I have done so far.

1. SSL enable tomcat (I can access https://mydomain.com:9443)
2. Import client certificate to server truststore
3. Change server-xml and make clientAuth="want" in my server.xml

   ```
   Connector port="9443" 
   protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
   SSLEnabled="true"
   maxThreads="150" 
   scheme="https" 
   secure="true"
   clientAuth="want" 
   sslProtocol="TLS" 
   keystoreFile="c:\serverkeystore"
   keystorePass="ChangeIt" />
   ```
4. Added **x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.*?)," user-service-ref="customUserDetailService"**  under **http** in my security-context.xml

   ```
   < http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
       < x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.?)," user-service-ref="myUserDetailService" />
      < intercept-url pattern="/upload" requires-channel="https" />
      < intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
       < form-login login-page="/login.jsp" 
                  default-target-url="/index.jsp"

                  authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=1"  />
       < logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/loggedout.jsp" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
   ```
5. add **< intercept-url pattern="/upload" requires-channel="https" />** to secure url
6. *myUserDetailService* is implementing UserDetailsService and returns UserDetails object (same class I use for form-based authentication, based on databased stored username, password, ROLES).

My problem is what ever URL path (even with /upload) it always show me the login.jsp page.

I am using Spring and Spring security 3.1.3 with tomcat 6.0.35

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Michael Sorry I couldn't yet try it out as we were busy with other issues. Will do as soon as I can.

Comment: Did you success to test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate problems:

1. Authenticate by client certificate authentication all `/upload` URLs
2. Authenticate by form authentication other URLs

The following configuration will allow to solve these problems separately in SpringSecurity 3.1:

```
<http pattern="/upload/**" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.?)," user-service-ref="myUserDetailService" />
</http>

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" 
           default-target-url="/index.jsp"
           authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=1"  />
    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/loggedout.jsp" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
</http>
```

Comment: Will try it Michael. Thanks!